# Changing 'upload_max_filesize' in php.ini does not change the value in phpinfo()

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp, bitnami

I'm using Wordpress via Bitnami + Xampp and am trying to change the `upload_max_filesize` variable since 2M is way too small. So I change it to 64M as shown here:

[image: php.ini file]

I also have `post_max_size=64M`.

However, Wordpress still shows that the max upload size is only 2M.

[image: Only 2M?]

I went to `phpinfo()` to look into the issue. I am editing the correct php.ini file that is being pointed too. And, on top of that, `phpinfo()` shows that `upload_max_filesize` is still set to 2M!

[image: What in the hell...]

Yes, I did restart the Apache server on Xampp (by clicking stop, then start). And I tried changing some Wordpress defined variables as described in [this blog post](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/is-the-wordpress-upload-limit-giving-you-trouble-heres-how-to-change-it#highlighter_248264).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured it out. Problem is, I'm not sure how it worked.

So I was using port 8080 since port 80 wasn't working for some reason. After restarting my computer, I started Apache up again. This time, it didn't work on port 8080. So I changed it back to port 80 and now, well, it works.

No idea why this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Common mistake is to assume that changing `upload_max_filesize` is sufficient. It is not. Because file upload goes via POST request you must also change `post_max_size` which must be **at least** the same value (I'd add a bit atop).

Comment: have you restarted your httpd?

Comment: By "restarted your httpd" do you mean restarting the Apache server?

Comment: yep. if you use apache this is your httpd

Comment: Yes I did. As I explained, I went to Xampp and stopped and started the Apache server.